# Looking for an example, in a topological vector space, of a convex body with an empty interior

Tags: vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In additional to the standard definition of "the interior of a set" in a topological space, [Kolmogorov & Fomin](https://archive.org/details/IntroductoryRealAnalysis/page/n68/mode/1up?q=interior) define (sec. 14.1) another concept of "interior" in a real vector space that does not require a topology: the interior $I(E)$ of a set $E$ in a vector space is the set of all such $x \in E$ that, for every vector $y$ there exists a positive $\epsilon_{y}$ (generally dependent on $y$, so a weaker requirement than "open neighborhood") all the vectors $x + ty, \; |t| < \epsilon$, lie in $E$.

Intuitively, this latter concept of interior (henceforth, *non-topological interior*) is the set of all points from which, no matter what direction you go, you must go a "positive distance" before you can leave $E$.  This distance depends on the direction, so the concept is weaker than the standard topological interior.

So, in a real topological vector space, the (standard topological) interior of a set $E$ is contained in the non-topological interior $I(E)$.  I am looking for examples of sets $E$ with an empty interior, but nonempty $I(E)$.

Comment: The definition of non-topological interior doesn't seem to imply convexity. Is that an additional assumption in your question?

Comment: For finite dimensional real vector spaces, it looks to me like the concepts are equivalent, since the boundary of a ball is compact, and so $\epsilon_y$ attains its minimum as a function of $y$. For the infinite dimensional case, are we talking about real Hilbert spaces, or is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ OK? If the latter, with what topology?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss, the latter: general topological vector spaces, with whatever topology.  And yes to your first comment.  Thank you!

Comment: Without convexity, here's an example in $\mathbb R^2$ showing that the two interiors are different: $$\{(x,y):y\geq x^2\lor y\leq-x^2\lor y=0\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ is a Banach and $0 \in C \subset E$ is a closed convex subset with $0 \in I(C)$ then $C$ has nonempty interior (in fact, $0$ is adherent to the interior of $C$).

*Proof*: let $S \subset E$ be the unit sphere, and $U_n=\{y \in S,\, y/n \in S\}$. Then each $U_n$ is a closed subset of $S$, and $S=\cup_n{U_n}$. So by Baire, there exist some $n \geq 1$, $V \subset S$ nonempty open, such that $V \subset U_n$. Then $(0,1/n)V \subset C$ is a nonempty open subset whose closure contains $0$.

---

So, if we want to try and find closed convex $C$ with empty interiors but $I(C) \neq \emptyset$, we need to consider non-complete spaces.

Let $E$ be the space of real sequences with finitely many nonzero terms, with the uniform norm (ie $\|u\|=\max_n\,|u_n|$).

Take $C=\{u \in E|\, \forall n,\, |nu_n| \leq 1\}$. Then you can easily check that $0 \in I(C)$ while $C$ has empty interior.